# Access a property of model field using a form in template

Tags: python, django

We are building a Django application and have a model with two classes:

```
class Category_Specialization (models.Model):
  name = models.CharField(max_length=50)

class Specialization (models.Model):
  specialization_name = models.CharField (max_length=60)
  category = models.ForeignKey(Category_Specialization)

class User (models.Model):
[...]
  specialization = models.ManyToManyField (Specialization)
```

We have created a form for showing a checkbox for the field user:

```
class SpecializationForm(forms.ModelForm):
def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
  super(UserServiceForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
  self.helper = FormHelper()
  self.helper.form_class = 'form-horizontal'
  self.helper.render_hidden_fields = True
  self.helper.form_tag = False
  self.helper.label_class = 'col-lg-2'
  self.helper.field_class = 'col-lg-10'

  self.helper.layout = Layout(
    'specialization',
    FormActions(
      Submit('submit', 'Create profile'),
    )
  )
  class Meta:
    model = User
    fields = ['specialization']
    widgets = {
    'specialization' : forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple,
    }
```

We have defined 4 categories, and 2 specialization for category. Now we want to show all the Categories in a template, with their specialization inside.

So, in the view we make:

```
list_categories = Category_Specialization.objects.order_by('name')
forms = UserSpecializationForm(request.POST or None, instance=request.user)

return render (request, 'users/profile/specialization.html', {
  'list_categories' : list_categories,
  'forms' : forms,
})
```

And in our template we try to do:

```
<form action="{% url 'users:specialization'  %}" method="post">
{% csrf_token %}

{% for category in list_categories %}
  <fieldset>
  <legend>{{category.name}}</legend>
  {% for form in forms %}
    {% for form_field in form %}
      {% if form_field.field.category.name == category.name %}
       {% load crispy_forms_tags %}
       {{form_field}}
       {% crispy form %}
      {% endif %}
    {% endfor %}
  {% endfor %}
  </fieldset>
{% endfor %}
```

The problem is that our IF is not working because we are not accessing correctly to the category-name

So, how can we access to the category name of the field in the for-loop to show the form in the correct category?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For me it's a better aproach using a custom widget definition.

put in your form.py:

```
class SpecializationByCategory(forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple):
def render(self, name, value, attrs=None, choices=()):
    if value is None: value = []
    has_id = attrs and 'id' in attrs
    final_attrs = self.build_attrs(attrs, name=name)
    output = [u'<ul>']
    # Normalize to strings
    str_values = set([force_unicode(v) for v in value])
    categories = Category_Specialization.objects.all()
    #for supercategory in supercategories:
    for category in categories:
        output.append(u'<li>%s</li>'%(category.name))
        output.append(u'<ul>')
        del self.choices
        self.choices = []
        specializations = Specialization.objects.filter(category=category)
        print specializations
        for specialization in specializations:
            self.choices.append((specialization.id,specialization.specialization_name))
            for i, (option_value, option_label) in enumerate(chain(self.choices, choices)):
                if has_id:
                    final_attrs = dict(final_attrs, id='%s_%s' % (attrs['id'], i))
                    label_for = u' for="%s"' % final_attrs['id']
                else:
                    label_for = ''
                cb = forms.CheckboxInput(final_attrs, check_test=lambda value: value in str_values)
                option_value = force_unicode(option_value)
                rendered_cb = cb.render(name, option_value)
                option_label = conditional_escape(force_unicode(option_label))
                output.append(u'<li><label%s>%s %s</label></li>' % (label_for, rendered_cb, option_label))
        output.append(u'</ul>')
        output.append(u'</li>')
    output.append(u'</ul>')
    return mark_safe(u'\n'.join(output))
```

And in the SpecializationForm, use the widget as this:

```
widgets = {
        'specialization' : SpecializationByCategory,
    }
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

In your view, I would suggest using a dictionary to pass it through. This sort of logic would work much better on the server side. Then you can loop over the keys and values in your template. Something like this:

```
list_categories = {'cat1': {'spec1': foo1, 'spec2': bar1, }, 'cat2': {'spec1': foo2, 'spec2': bar2, }, }
```

Then on the template:

```
{% load crispy_forms_tags %}
{% for category, specs in list_categories %}
    <fieldset>
        <legend>{{category.name}}</legend>
        {% for spec, name in specs %}
            {{ form_field }}
        {% endfor %}
    </fieldset>
{% endfor %}
```

The load should be outside any loops so you don't load try and load it every time. It can go at the top of your template.